# Has Apple’s FairPlay DRM been cracked?

Tags: drm, apple-books

I am not asking *how*. I am asking the binary Yes/No question of whether Apple’s [FairPlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FairPlay) [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) copy-protection as used on their [iBooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBooks) ebook content is known to have been cracked/broken/breached, citing evidence.

According to [this CNET article in 2012](http://www.cnet.com/news/has-apples-ibooks-fair-play-drm-been-cracked/), that version of FairPlay was breached. Rumors suggest Apple enhanced FairPlay. I am simply asking for a definitive answer as to the current situation of 2016.

Comment: Dear Drive-By Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it but this program claims to be able to remove DRM without affecting the book. http://www.remove-drm.com/ibook-drm-removal-mac.html

If this can be confirmed as working you have your answer (yes)